# Joining two tables and while pivoting sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have two tables like so

Table1

```
SegmentNo  PassingPotencies
1           8
2           10
```

Table2

```
BatchAvg     Total   TotalSegments  TotalPassed
106.22        20          2            18
```

I want to join two tables with a simple login. If the Passingpotencies in table 1 is not equal to 10 then the segment is failed and vice versa.  The final result should look something like this

TableResult

```
BatchAvg     Total     TotalSegments     TotalPassed     Segment1     Segment2
106.22         20           2               18              Fail        Pass
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do these two tables join though? Is there a batch number in both I take it?

Comment: Sorry, there is no relation between these tables at the moment. They are completely separate.

Comment: No not possible unless there a relationship b/w the tables by means of some common column

Comment: Then how do you choose to compare with 1st or 2nd row in Table1?

Comment: Oh I see. You compare by SegmentNo. Is that it? And can you have any number of segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current design, this is what you can achieve (something closest).

See a demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e86f5/5

```
select distinct BATCHAVG,
TOTAL,
TOTALSEGMENTS,
TOTALPASSED,
SegmentNo,
case when PASSINGPOTENCIES <> 10 then 'Failed'
else 'Passed' end as SegmentStatus
from
(
select * from table2,table1
 ) X
```

Above query will results in

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping. You gave me a fresh perspective.

Answer (score 1):

This will work in your actual scenario. See a Demo here: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d88a/1/0)

**First, join both tables:**

```
SELECT 
    T2.BATCHAVG
,   T2.TOTAL
,   T2.TOTALSEGMENTS
,   T2.TOTALPASSED
,   T1.SEGMENTNO
,   (CASE WHEN T1.PASSINGPOTENCIES >= 10 THEN 'PASSED' ELSE 'FAILED' END)   AS SEGMENT
INTO TABLE3
FROM TABLE1 T1
CROSS JOIN TABLE2 T2
```

**Then, select this table like this. It's some kind of PIVOT:**

```
SELECT 
    T.BATCHAVG
,   T.TOTAL
,   T.TOTALSEGMENTS
,   T.TOTALPASSED
,   MAX(T.SEGMENT1)     AS SEGMENT1
,   MAX(T.SEGMENT2)     AS SEGMENT2
FROM (
SELECT 
    T1.BATCHAVG
,   T1.TOTAL
,   T1.TOTALSEGMENTS
,   T1.TOTALPASSED
,   (CASE WHEN T1.SEGMENTNO = '1' THEN T1.SEGMENT END) AS SEGMENT1
,   (CASE WHEN T1.SEGMENTNO = '2' THEN T1.SEGMENT END) AS SEGMENT2
FROM TABLE3 T1
) T
GROUP BY
    T.BATCHAVG
,   T.TOTAL
,   T.TOTALSEGMENTS
,   T.TOTALPASSED
```